# disable sudo/root privilege from node.js script

Tags: node.js, linux, root, sudo, privileges

I need in my node.js application sudo privileges to run server on port 80, or run some others startup administration stuff. 
But when I will do that I don't want this privileges anymore because then I will run some external libraries from node_modules.

So, how can I disable my administration privileges from node.js script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
process.setgid('somegroup');
process.setuid('someuser');
```

See the docs:

- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setgid_id
- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setuid_id

See this article for more info:

- https://thomashunter.name/blog/drop-root-privileges-in-node-js/

### Other options

Another way to bind to low ports without running as root would be to give a capability to bind to low ports if your system supports it - using e.g. CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE on Linux with something like:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/your/program
```

That way you will not have to run it as root and you will not have to change to a different user later.

Comment: Thanks, but in this method I have to know the name of user and group which might be different/unknown on different machines, right?

Comment: @Tunga That's right. If you're running as root then you'll have to change to a different user. Some systems like OpenBSD may allow you to drop certain privileges. On Linux instead of running as root you can use setcap to add just the priviledge to bind to low ports. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again @rsp